# xUnit Tests hang on Run all

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, xunit

My application is an ASP.NET Core application.

I used to test my application with MSTest, but decided to swap to xUnit.
All my tests passed when I ran them all in MSTest.
However, if I run them all with xUnit, it seems like a random amount of tests finish and then it hangs. No tests fail, they just hang.

I tried to change the default Processor Architecture to X64 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/611).

If I just mark one single test, and run only this one, it will finish.
I tried this with every test and it worked for all of them.

so my problem is the testrunner just hangs if I click the Run All button.

Iam using 
  xUnit Version 2.2.0
    Visual Studio 2017

Thank you very much

Comment: Have tried to (temporarily) disable the parallel processing of the tests? You can do this by simply adding the following attribute to the AssemblyInfo file: `[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]` (for more informations on that subject see the following link: [Running Tests in Parallel](https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html))

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Yes I did try this and it didn't work..

Comment: Do you use `.Wait` anywhere?

Comment: any luck on this?

Comment: I get this same behavior with .Net Framework 4.5. My tests all pass in Test Explorer, but in ReSharper Unit test sessions it hangs after about 65 tests. I have xunit.core 2.1.0 in VS 2017, Resharper 2017.2.

Comment: Sometimes `xUnit` tests hang forever because the test runner pipeline can't handle parallel threads. To check if that's the issue try what's described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56431247/804385).

Comment: The close message says it needs debugging details. But having experienced this myself, that's the problem! There is no simple repro and no obvious cause. Furthermore, at least for me, it is inconsistent whether or not the problem will occur.